# Print either parenthesized year or bracketed number depending on biblatex style?

Tags: biblatex

How can one cite either the parenthesized year or bracketed number, depending on whether `authoryear` or `numeric` styles are used?  For instance, I would like to have one unified piece of code that prints "Knuth's work (1984) ..." if `authoryear` is used, and that prints "Knuth's work [1] ..." if `numeric` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
% \usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
% Works for authoryear style, but not numeric style
\Citeauthor{knuth:ct:a}'s work \parentext{\citeyear{knuth:ct:a}}

% Works for numeric style, but not authoryear style
\Citeauthor{knuth:ct:a}'s work \autocite{knuth:ct:a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the starred variant of `\autocite` does the trick.  For the example from the question, you would use `\Citeauthor{knuth:ct:a}'s work \autocite*{knuth:ct:a}` for both the `authoryear` and `numeric` styles.